# Tools for interactive type-2 (SCD) work?

Tags: database

Are there any good tools for interactive type-2 SCD work?  I'm looking for both analysis (e.g., "what changed between date_1 and date_2?") and execution (e.g., "update my type-2 table with this new data").

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration (a.k.a. Spoon, a.k.a. Kettle, ...) right now, and it's a bit awkward at the execution side, and I'm not sure if it does the analysis side at all.  I'd definitely love to try something that might be better.